# How can I determine the max allowable WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE for a wx GLCanvas?

Tags: python, wxpython, pyopengl

I am creating a `wx.Frame` with a `GLCanvas`.  On some platforms, setting the `WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE` attribute of the canvas to 32 works fine.  On another platform, I just get a blank frame (the `GLCanvas` doesn't render) unless I reduce the depth size to 16.  Is there an easy way in the calling code to determine the allowable values for the depth size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to use GLCanvas method [`IsDiplaySupported`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/glcanvas.GLCanvas.html), however it seems that this method is available in wxPython 2.9 and not older versions.

Comment: This is exactly what I need (at least for wx >= 2.9). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Linux? Perhaps you could get that information from the table of display modes that `glxinfo -t` outputs.

Comment: I'm currently running on RHEL and OS X (both of which have glxinfo) but the code is also used by Windows users so I would like to find a platform-independent way of pulling that info. +1 for something that will work on unix/linux-based systems.

Comment: This is not much useful, how can I get the value from the output of the command? There are many values. And of course it's not platform independent.